# Extracting in between substring of two strings in a website

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have [this site](https://www.zacks.com/commentary/99386/new-strong-buy-stocks-for-december-29th). I want to extract the symbols that appear below the title of the article, (EXAS,ESNT,ENZ,CENT,AEE). I am a beginner, so I tried a rather anti-pythonic approach:

```
import requests
link="https://www.zacks.com/commentary/99386/new-strong-buy-stocks-for-december-29th"
fetch_data = requests.get(link)
content = str((fetch_data.content))
# I know that in the source code the symbols appear between "tickers" and "publish_date" therefore:
tickers= "tickers :"
pd = "publish_date :"
Z= ("%s(.*)%s" % (tickers,pd))
result = re.search(Z, content)
print (result)
# Just printing out the substring between tickers and pd
Output: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(95142, 95213), match="tickers : [\\'EXAS\\',\\'ESNT\\',\\'ENZ\\',\\'CEN>
```

How can I print out just the symbols? Also, the last symbol 'CEN' should be printed out as 'CENT' and 'AEE' symbol is also missing. This would be ideal

```
Symbols: EXAS, ESNT, ENZ, CENT, AEE
```

Or at least:

```
"tickers : [\\'EXAS\\',\\'ESNT\\',\\'ENZ\\',\\'CENT\\',\\'AEE\\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the first group and clean it up:

```
>>> tickers = result.groups()[0]
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', tickers)[0].split("\\'")[1::2]
['EXAS', 'ESNT', 'ENZ', 'CENT', 'AEE']
```